# Allocating a generic struct in Zig lang

Tags: allocator, zig

Is it possible to create allocation for `struct` that contains type as an attribute ?

For example

Example struct is

```
const Content = struct {
    content: type,
    name: []const u8,
};
```

Then, i would like to allocate memory for example of `2` * `Content`

I know i could use

```
const list: [2]CustomElement = .{ Content{ .content = Type, .name = "test" }, Content{ .content = Type, .name = "test" } };
```

But how to achieve them same thing using `allocators` ?

This doesn't work.

```
  comptime {
        var list = std.ArrayList(Content).init(test_allocator);
        try list.append(Content{ .content = MyType , .name = "test" });
    }
```

I get error

```
error: parameter of type '*std.array_list.ArrayListAligned(Content,null)' must be declared comptime
```

**For short**

Is it possible to build functionality for something like `Box` does in Rust ?

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, I don't think the allocators currently available in the language (0.6.0 at the time of writing), which usually require a 'comptime` type parameter, currently permit this.

From the current [documentation](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#comptime) relating to `comptime`, concerning the `type` type:

> In Zig, types are first-class citizens. They can be assigned to
> variables, passed as parameters to functions, and returned from
> functions. However, they can only be used in expressions which are
> known at compile-time, which is why the parameter T in the above
> snippet must be marked with comptime.

It does seem like something that should be possible, in that I think `type` must have a size, and you could probably allocate a structure that could hold it.

It does look like the `comptime` allocation is a use case that might be supported in upcoming versions: https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/1291, but I'm not sure how that would interact with `type`.

I'm a fairly new to Zig, so hopefully someone will provide a more complete answer =D

**Edit**: I'm sure it isn't the question you're asking, but if, like in the example above, you're only storing objects with the same type in the list, I guess you could do something with generics?

e.g.

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() anyerror!void {
    const cw = ContentWrapper(MyType);

    var list = std.ArrayList(cw.Content).init(std.heap.page_allocator);
    try list.append(cw.Content{ .content = MyType{ .id = 1, .property = 30 }, .name = "First" });
    try list.append(cw.Content{ .content = MyType{ .id = 2, .property = 10 }, .name = "Second" });
}

const MyType = struct {
    id: u8, property: f32
};

fn ContentWrapper(comptime T: type) type {
    return struct {
        pub const Content = struct {
            content: T, name: []const u8
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: Hey,
Thanks for the answer, 

basically i wanted to know, if i can do in Zig something like `Box` does in Rust.

But i think you are right, i should just rethink my way of doing things in Zig, probably there's better way for doing it  :)

Comment: Interesting, I guess you could wrap up some memory allocation functions in a generic boxer of some kind (using an allocator), probably wouldn't be as neat though. Looks like there are a few open issues relating to memory management for the future, hopefully someone comes and gives a more helpful answer =D